# Got console error `unexpected token <` from sign in page (using keystonejs 4.0 beta4)

Tags: express, webpack, keystonejs, mern

I've added keystone to my existing MERN server with webpack. Server started with no error.

However, when I try to access `/keystone/signin` (which redirected by `/keystone`) it gives a blank page and console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` from `signin?from=/keystone/js/packages.js:1` and `signin?from=/keystone/js/signin.js:1`

The content in signin.js is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sign in to OneCharge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/keystone/styles/keystone.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="signin-view"></div>
    <script>
      var Keystone = {"adminPath":"/keystone","brand":"My Site","csrf":{"header":{"x-csrf-token":"vIRAZlZwZae640a645fd60ed9e8ca9911111a05ce088c8095c"}},"from":"/keystone/js/signin.js","userCanAccessKeystone":false};
    </script>
    <script src="/keystone/js/packages.js"></script>
    <script src="/keystone/js/signin.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any hints to solve that could help.

Comment: I don't know anything about keystone, but it sounds to me like the server is serving a fallback HTML instead of a script file.

Comment: Thanks, is anything related to webpack/express that I need to re-config?

Comment: I don't know your configuration or needs, so I cannot say. If it is what I think it is, I could only advise to look at dev tool's "network" tab and see if there are any requests for JS files that are responded with HTML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, answering my own question here.

Turns out following the guide here doesn't work for me [How to add keystone to an existing express app](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/How-to-Add-Keystone-to-an-Already-Existing-Express-App).

After looking up the code from keystone repository. I found a [test project](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-test-project) that have everything I need and maybe other people who want to use keystone.

I followed the configuration from the test project repo and work like a charm!